# Should I test a model class which sync often to the server?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, xcode, nsnotifications

And how do I do it, since obviously there are a lot of async methods, and no way (that I know of) to check them in a unit test.

For example:

```
- (void) testSomeTest {
// things
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(helperTestSomeTest:)
name:connectionFinished
object:nil];
// connect to server
}
- (void) helperTestSomeTest:(NSNotification)notification {
 STAssertWhatever(whathever, nil); // not working
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a variety of solutions to Unit test this. [Mock objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object), [Stubs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_stubs), and Fakes all come to mind.

They seem similar, but [this is a great look at the differences](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TheDifferenceBetweenMocksAndStubs).

By the way, to directly answer your question-line: Yes, test 100% of the code. **Everything**.